# Search for non-characters (character replacement indicators)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vim, encoding, libreoffice-calc, ascii

I have a text file (actually a .csv exported from .xlsx in LibreOffice) with lines that have gibberish when opened in LibreOffice Calc. In VIM they appear as the following:

```
Joe User, joe@user.com, p@ss<96>w0rd
```

The `<96>` *was* some funny character that was similar to `-`, but MS Office decided to change it to something else. The file is therefore *not* ASCII:

```
$ file -i Users.csv
Users.csv: text/plain; charset=unknown-8bit
```

Note that all of these 'funny' characters have codepoints less than 127, so I really don't know how Calc and VIM realize that this is not ASCII. **What other encodings have all the code points below 127, i.e. are not ASCII compatible? Also, how can I search for these characters in VIM?** For non-ASCII characters above 127 I use `/[^\x00-\x127]` to search, but of course that will not find `<96>`.

The original .xlsx file is still found on another user's Windows computer, and sure enough I can verify in his MS Office that the `<96>` character is not ASCII 96 <kbd>`</kbd> but rather some funny variation on <kbd>'</kbd>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<96>` is not ASCII 96: it is the representation of UTF-8 `U+0096` (part of latin 1 extended), "start of protected area", whatever that means.

You can hit `ga` to see information on the character under the cursor. For `<96>`, you'd get the following:

```
<<96>> 150, Hex 0096, Octal 226
```

You can remove that character from your buffer with:

```
:%s/<C-v>u0096//g
```

which should look like:

```
:%s/<96>//g
```

Or you can do:

```
:%s/\%u0096//g    " hex form
```

or:

```
:%s/\%d150//g     " decimal form
```

or:

```
:%/\%o226//g      " octal form
```

See `:help ga`, `:help utf-8-typing`, `:help \%u`.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that `<96>` is decimal, I did not realize that it is hexadecimal, and therefore above \x7F (127). Thank you!